# How is golang statically typed when it also allows not specifying any type for a variable

Tags: go

All of these work in golang:
`var i int = 2`
`var i = 2`
`i := 2`
Why are we saying golang is statically typed? It should be dynamically typed right?

If golang is performing type resolution during compile time, then it should be increasing the compile time of the program, so why is golang known for its faster compile time?

Comment: It's statically typed because you can't change a variable's type at runtime. Not specifying a variable's type *explicitly* does not mean that that variable does not have a type, in these situations "type inference" is used. e.g. the compiler looks looks at the RHS of the expression, sees `2`, and decides, based on rules enumerated in the spec, what type to give to the variable.

Comment: Example: In a dynamic language like JavaScript you can do the following: `x = 123; x = "foo"; console.log(x);` (you can try it out in the browser's console). In a statically typed language like Go you cannot do: `x := 123; x = "foo"; fmt.Println(x)` ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/fpsBWEKkADH)). The second statement will cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting @mkopriva's answer.

It's statically typed because you can't change a variable's type at runtime. Not specifying a variable's type explicitly does not mean that variable does not have a type, in these situations "type inference" is used. e.g. the compiler looks looks at the RHS of the expression, sees 2, and decides, based on rules enumerated in the spec, what type to give to the variable.

Answer (score 4):

In all these instances, `i` is an integer. In the case of `i := 2`, the variable `i` is implicitly an integer. You could later assign `51` or `42` to `i`, but you could not assign any other datatype to is.

Go just [implicitly](https://go.dev/tour/basics/10) infers the datatype from the initial assignment.

Comment: Don't forget that `nil` can only be assigned to pointers / interfaces, not primitives.

Comment: Also, nil values still have a type if assigned to variables: https://go.dev/play/p/yiLbxxJcyD4

Comment: Thanks, to clear things up for this specific case I removed the mention of `nil`.